# Timer no progresa adecuadamente con JprogressBar

Tags: java

Chicos lo que estoy intentando es que el progresso del JprogressBar sea el mismo que el del timer. La variable max son los segundos que dura una canción, me gustaria cuadrar lo que dura una cancion con el jprogresBar

```
public void musicBar(String nom) throws SQLException {

    pb = this.V_Client.ProgressBar;
    pb.setValue(0);
    int max = CançoDAO.returnSec(nom);

    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
        int counter = 0;


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            counter++;
            pb.setValue(counter);
            System.out.println(counter);
            if (counter == max) {
                time.stop();
            }
        }
    };

    time = new Timer( 1000 , listener);
    time.start();
}
```

Comment: A pb no hay que declararle el maximo?

Comment: pb.setMaximum(max); sigue sin cuadrar, el progress bar acaba 15 segundos mas o menos antes

Comment: y el valor de max y counter supongo que es el mismo.. estara tomando mal la cantidad de segundo de la cancion?

Comment: en teoría no el contador suma++ cada 1000ms que es 1 sec, y el contador termina a los 152 sec que es lo que dura exactamente la cancion

Comment: me he fijado bien y el contador no esta sumando cada 1 segundo lo hace un pelin más rápido

Comment: ahhh... eso te estaba por preguntar, si no habia un delay que provocara eso... ya ahi, necesitamos un experto...

Comment: lo que he hecho es poner en vez de 1000 ms poner 1100 y parece que cuadra, pero es poco lógico

Comment: en realidad no del todo.. calcula que no solo esta ejecutando el timer, esta ejecutando la musica y mostrando los cambios en pantalla...